# Implemenet attention in vanilla encoder-decoder architecture

Tags: tensorflow, keras, attention-model, encoder-decoder, neural-mt

I have tried a vanila enc-dec arch as following (english to french NMT)

[image: My encoder-decoder architecture]

> I want to know how to integrate keras attention layer here. Either from the [keras docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention) or any other attention module from third party repo is also welcome. I just need to integrate it and see how it works and finetune it.

> **Full code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/sayan1999/d008ef965c72371602c399284b7ab189)**.

Not showing any code in this post because it's large and complex.

Comment: Where do you want to add your attention layer?

Comment: That's what I want to know actually, from the docs I know you gotta generate the attention weights from decoder  and encoder inputs. I want something by doing changes in this existing architecture. this is a french to english translation architecture.

Comment: @AniketBote I have implemented what I was looking for, have put an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have resolved the issue. I am using a third-party-attention [layer](https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/blob/master/src/layers/attention.py) by [Thushan Ganegedara](https://github.com/thushv89/). Used it's Attentionlayer class. And integrated that in my architecture as following.

[image: Architecture with attention]